# Map Maven artifacts to Debian packages

Tags: java, maven, build, dependencies, deb

I have to create Debian packages for all applications in my current project. These are the standalone applications that are launched like "java -jar ....". 
Each project provides its own JAR artifact which depends on a couple of other project artifacts and there are lot of 3-rd party dependencies (both compile and runtime).

Right now I can build a debian package that includes all needed JARs (dependencies with transitives, some resource files, scripts etc).

I also specify the JRE Debian dependency in a control file configuration for my packages, so that java is installed as well.

I create deb packages with codehaus unix-maven-plugin.

The JARs are installed to /usr/share/java, scripts to /usr/bin etc.

As long as I install exactly one package on a server it is fine: installation and runtime succeeds. But if there is already some software installed that provides one of the JARs that my package contains (for example slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar) I have problems installing the package. The package manager complains about file conflicts. That happens also when I try to install two my applications to the same server that obviously provide set of same jar files.

The solution for my problem would be not to include the JAR files that are available by other debian packages and instead declaring those packages in the "Depends" section of control file. 
Of curse not every JAR from maven repository has corresponding debian package available, but for those missing artifacts I can create other debian packages myself.

Are there any available ways to convert the maven dependencies into the list of debian dependencies ("Depends" section in control file) so that my delivery does not redistribute JAR files that are available as external debian packages?

Is there any online service that I can use in my custom maven plugin to find the debian packages that might provide the JARs I need for my application?

Thank you

Comment: http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar&mode=path&suite=stable&arch=any or `apt-file` allows you to search Debian for existing packages containing files you need. http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas/list?name=maven searches for Ubuntu PPAs but they might work for you on Debian as well (did not find anything very close to what you're asking for, but perhaps you'll have better luck and/or skillz.)

Comment: Thank you, tripleee, for you suggestion, that is still not exactly what I look for, but at least some little step forward :) The online service you referenced could find some packages for the JARs I need. Is such service available for any repository? We have a corporate in-house APT repository as well, do we need to install something there to do similar queries?

Comment: http://pkgs.org/ was recently referenced in another question, try that too?  Alas, it doesn't seem to cover third-party repositories.  `apt-file` will search the contents of all the repositories you have in your `sources.list` or equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'jdeb-maven-plugin' to create debian packages https://github.com/tcurdt/jdeb